# Calling in sick and no sick leave available

Tags: human-resources

I have no sick leave available but had to call in sick.  Is my employer allowed to call me and make me come in to work?

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: While the company policy and local law my vary, most likely it will be unpaid leave and any reasonable employer will not call a sick person to work. (it is endangering not only you but others in the office)

Comment: Agree with @PagMax, though unfortunately not all employers are reasonable...

Comment: I agree @DavidK. It is just that with the information given by OP, it is not clear how 'reasonable' is their employer.  Hopefully it works out well!

Comment: Why do you have no sick leave available?

Comment: No you are not a slave they can not make you come in to work.  But that does not mean that choosing not to will be free of consequence.

Comment: Was it an unconditional order to come to work or did they say "If you want to get paid you have to come to work"?

Answer (score 3):

No one can compel you to attend work if you are sick.

Depending on your contract & regularity of your sick days they can start disciplinary proceedings or even sack you though.

Comment: Employers cannot simply fire anyone for taking too many sick days. They are subject to FMLA: "The Family and Medical Leave Act of 1993 (FMLA) is a United States federal law requiring covered employers to provide employees with job-protected and unpaid leave for qualified medical and family reasons."

Comment: The question does not state a country, so the FMLA may not apply.

Answer (score 2):

More likely you have to take it as unpaid leave.  This will obviously have an unhappy impact on your paycheck.  Taking unpaid leave can also impact your accrual/earning of future paid leave, employer share of benefits like health insurance, etc, which can also impact the paycheck.

Also, if you've already used up all of your leave and need to take even more, the company might scrutinize your work attendance and determine if you have an issue with chronic "absenteeism," which can affect evaluations and even your future employment.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, leave of any sort can be disapproved. Employers can make someone come in when sick or lose their jobs or have some sort of HR write-up. It happens frequently in service industries. Employers can require a doctor's note if they think you are faking. Employers can refuse to pay you anything if you have no sick leave even if you have vacation time available (Most won't of course, but there are bad companies to work for).

The rules could be drastically different depending on the country.

Comment: Totally incorrect. FMLA specifically protects Family Medical Leave. A doctor's note is not required to prove illness in FMLA and employees don't have to even invoke any special "I'm taking FMLA language" to be subject to it. Specifically: "The Family and Medical Leave Act of 1993 (FMLA) is a United States federal law requiring covered employers to provide employees with job-protected and unpaid leave for qualified medical and family reasons."

Comment: FMLA is for long term leave not short-term sick leave.